# API POST method to save a file to another system drive is throwing a 500 error

Tags: asp.net-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a .NetCore 3 API controller that can take a POST request.

However, I want it to save the file on a different drive.

```
F:\GameFiles\Media\UserScreens\Uploads
```

I am setting the path in my method as you see below.

But whenever I hit it with Postman for testing, it just says it encountered a generic 500 error.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostUserMedia([FromForm] IFormFile imageFile)
{

    string contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;

    var uploads = Path.Combine(contentRootPath, "F:\GameFiles\Media\UserScreens\Uploads");
    var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, imageFile.FileName);

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await imageFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

In Postman, the address is: http://x.x.x.x/api/GameFilesAndMedia

I am using 'form-data' for the body and selecting a test file when prompted by Postman.

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include an example request that causes the 500 error?

Comment: @TamásSzabó I added the sample Postman request

Comment: You are trying to combine two absolute paths, aren't you? `contentRootPath` is where the app is running, and then you are trying to concatenate `F:/...` to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a folder outside of the application, directly specify the location of the file upload：

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostUserMedia([FromForm] IFormFile imageFile)
{

    var filePath = Path.Combine(@"F:\GameFiles\Media\UserScreens\Uploads", imageFile.FileName);

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await imageFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use double backslashes in your path.

`"F:\\GameFiles\\Media\\UserScreens\\Uploads"` instead of `"F:\GameFiles\Media\UserScreens\Uploads"`

Comment: hi thanks! I tried that but still get the same generic 500 error in Postman.  I know the path is correct and double-checked this morning.